# Why I get [Laravel - Undefined variable: users (View..] if I tried to use POST and GET on the same view?

Tags: php, laravel, post, frameworks, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a simple search form using laravel.
the search page is supposed to be the same for results.
but I can't make it work, and i'm not sure why
It works on a different Route but can't get it to work on the same route.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('searchuser',function(){
return view('searchuser');

 })->middleware('auth');


Route::post('searchuser', function(){
$q = Input::get('name');
$users = App\User::where('name_en','like',$q)->get();

return view('searchuser', ['users' => $users]);

 });
```

**Blade:**

```
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="searchuser">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Search.." required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Search
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        {{$user->name_ar . '<br />'}}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the same route and the same blade template

within this blade template you are trying to access a variable .

which is defined in route `POST` and not defined the other `GET`

so your issue in your `GET` route not in your `POST` route;

to fix this , pass a default value to your `GET` route as follows :

```
Route::get('searchuser',function(){
return view('searchuser', ['users' => []]);

 })->middleware('auth');
```

**OR/AND** in your blade template do a little confirmation that the users variable isset

```
@if(isset($users))
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {{$user->name_ar . '<br />'}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched the names of your variables. You get the users as `$users2` variable in line:

```
  $users2 = App\User::where('name_en','like',$q)->get();
```

but then you send variable `$users` to the view (which does not exist):

```
return view('searchuser', ['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: I modified this mistake but it still doesn't work. and modified the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You have define a `$users2` and **passed** `$users` to your view

### Edit :

i believe your condition should be something like this:

```
$users = App\User::where('name_en','like','%' . $q . '%')->get();
```

Comment: I modified this mistake but it still doesn't work. and modified the code above.

Comment: Undefined variable: users

Comment: I have modified my answer check it an tell me what you get

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this**

```
Route::post('searchuser', function(){
    $q = Input::get('name'); //problem in your code
    $q = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('name'); //update
    $users2 = App\User::where('name_en','like',$q)->get();

    return view('searchuser', ['users' => $users2]);
});
```

> Use
>
> return view('searchuser', ['users' => $users2]);
>
> OR
>
> $users = App\User::where('name_en','like',$q)->get();

I follow 1st one

Comment: I modified this mistake but it still doesn't work. and modified the code above

Comment: Use this $q = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('name');

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.
At the first I sent a different variable name as every one noticed.

But I forgot to check if the $users variable isset or not before looping it.

so when I was trying to run the Get route I get the error because the PHP is right, I didn't send the variable $users yet.

so the simple modification was:

```
 @if(count($users))
      @foreach($users as $user)
            {{ $user->name_ar . '<br />' }}
      @endforeach
 @endif
```